# sqlite3 - promise for asynchronous calls

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, sqlite, promise

I want to select asynchronous some data of a sqlite3 database. But since `db.each` is a asynchron function my following `select` function doesn't work properly. **How to add a Promise to wait for the result?**

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();

export default function select(database, table) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const db = new sqlite3.Database(database);
    const queries = [];
    db.each(`SELECT rowid as key, * FROM ${table}`, (err, row) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
      console.log(`Push row ${row.key} from database.`);
      queries.push(row);
    });
    console.log(queries);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(queries));
  });
}
```

[image: result of codesnippet]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`db.each()` requires a slightly cumbersome, non-standard promisification due to the nature of its callbacks, through which it :

- delivers rows, one at a time, to a first callback,
- signals completion to a second callback.

Compare that with the standard pattern exhibited in `db.all()`, which takes a single callback with the signature `(err, rows)`.

Sticking with `db.each()`, what you have written is correct as far as it goes but stops short of resolving the Promise on completion of `db.each()`.

Fortunately the solution, despite being cumbersome, is fairly simple. `resolve(queries)` can be called from a second, callback.

```
export default function select(database, table) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const db = new sqlite3.Database(database);
        const queries = [];
        db.each(`SELECT rowid as key, * FROM ${table}`, (err, row) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err); // optional: you might choose to swallow errors.
            } else {
                queries.push(row); // accumulate the data
            }
        }, (err, n) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err); // optional: again, you might choose to swallow this error.
            } else {
                resolve(queries); // resolve the promise
            }
        });
    });
}
```

If the expected number of rows is "very limited" (as it says in the SQLite documentation), then use `db.all()` instead.

Comment: Doesn't this end up having to load the entire resultset into memory just like `all()` would? I don't have a better solution, I'm just a relative JS n00b and I'm trying to figure out how to be memory-efficient with big resultsets.

Comment: Yes but memory issues are not part of the question.

Comment: if memory isn't an issue then just add promises to all()