# Return statement not awaiting

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, discord, discord.js

When doing `return true` or `return false` it will not `await` those results and return `undefined`.
It does however do the `if` statement properly, just returning either `true` or `false` doesn't work

Console logs `undefined` before logging `row.channelOwner` which is what makes me think it's not awaiting the return.

(channel is the channel ID and user is the user ID)

```
client.on('message', async message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith('=test') || message.author.bot) return;
    const args = message.content.slice('=test'.length).trim().split(' ');
    
    var result = await cowner(args[0],args[1])
    console.log(result)
})

cowner = async function(channel, user) {
    let query = `SELECT channelOwner FROM voice WHERE channelID = ${channel}`

    db.each(query, [], async (err, row) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }

        console.log(row.channelOwner)
        console.log(user) // row.channelOwner and user is the same

        // It logs reached if and reached else so the if statement is working
        if (user === row.channelOwner) {
            console.log('reached if')
            return true;
        } else {
            console.log('reached else')
            return false;
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: you are returning from the anonymous function used inside db.each. But you are not returning anything from the `cowner` function, therefore it's returning undefined. Also async is unnecessary as you are not awaiting anything.

Comment: Using asyc/await does not convert callbacks into promises. Use the promise constructor instead.

Comment: @Timjime what does `db.each` return?

Comment: So if this is `sqlite3`, `db.each` runs through each row, but still doesn't change the fact that the callback does not return anything. Instead, you might want to use `db.all` or even `db.get` if the result is guaranteed to be only zero or one row and wrap this inside a `Promise`. Do read on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46994203/sqlite3-promise-for-asynchronous-calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Original answer edited out)

If this is SQLite3, then it's a bit complicated to use `each` to find if the user is a channel owner. I'd suggest using `db.all` or even `db.get` (because it seems that it only returns zero or one row, and no more) while wrapping them in a `Promise` like so:

If using `db.get()`

```
cowner = async function(channel, user) {
  let query = `SELECT channelOwner FROM voice WHERE channelID = ${channel}`

  const row = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.get(query, [], (err, row) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        reject(err)
      }

      resolve(row)
    })
  })

  console.log(row.channelOwner)
  console.log(user) // row.channelOwner and user is the same

  // It logs reached if and reached else so the if statement is working
  if (user === row.channelOwner) {
    console.log('reached if')
    return true;
  } else {
    console.log('reached else')
    return false;
  }
}
```

If using `db.all()`

```
cowner = async function(channel, user) {
  let query = `SELECT channelOwner FROM voice WHERE channelID = ${channel}`

  const rows = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.all(query, [], (err, rows) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        reject(err)
      }

      resolve(rows)
    })
  })

  // Iterate through the resulting rows and check if there is one row which channelOwner matches the user
  const isChannelOwner = rows.some(row => user === row.channelOwner)

  // It logs reached if and reached else so the if statement is working
  if (isChannelOwner) {
    console.log('reached if')
    return true;
  } else {
    console.log('reached else')
    return false;
  }
}
```

If you wish to keep using `each`, do read on the answer here: [sqlite3 - promise for asynchronous calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46994203/sqlite3-promise-for-asynchronous-calls)

Comment: This returns `Database {filename: 'voice.db', mode: 65542}` basically just all database info I think. I use sqlite3

Comment: I have updated the answer and removed the original text and codes because I didn't know we're referring to `sqlite`